# How to create a form that accepts two numbers and then pass them as arguments to a php calculator class?

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to create a form that accepts two numbers, then pass the two numbers as arguments to php calculator class and then add, subtract, multiply and divide them on request(on clicking their respective buttons). I have successfully created the calculator class and the form but I don't know hot to individually call the functions with the numbers as arguments. Here is my incomplete code

```
<?php
class MyCalculator {
public $_fval, $_sval;
public function __construct( $fval, $sval ) {
$this->_fval = $fval;
$this->_sval = $sval;
}
public function add() {
return $this->_fval + $this->_sval;
}
public function subtract() {
return $this->_fval - $this->_sval;
}
public function multiply() {
return $this->_fval * $this->_sval;
}
public function divide() {
return $this->_fval / $this->_sval;
}
}
?>

<html>
<body>

<form action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?> method='post'>
a: <input type="number" name="num-a"><br><br>

b: <input type="number" name="num-b"><br><br>

   <input type='button' value='add'>
   <input type='button' value='multiply'>
   <input type='button' value='subtract'>
   <input type='button' value='divide'>
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
 $x = $_POST['num-a']; 
 $y = $_POST['num-b']; 
?>
```

Please help, I am new to php

Comment: All you're really missing is `$calc = new MyCalculator($x, $y);` at the end. Then you can call functions from the `$calc` object and echo the results.

Comment: Oh and your form doesn't have anything which will cause it to be submitted to the server. `<input type="button"` doesn't send anything. You'd need `input type="submit"` and give each button a `name` and a `value` so the server can knows which one was clicked and what action it's asking for. TBH though you could do all this in JavaScript more easily, unless it's deliberately meant to be a PHP exercise.

Comment: To call a function of the class you need to create an object of it first, then using that object u can call any functions of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button form fields don't do much - they don't really work when posting data to a server, for example. They mostly exist to be used with JavaScript. What you want to use is a [radio button][1].

Then you should be able to print out your results for the end user. Below is an example of how you might be able to do this.

```php
<?php
class MyCalculator {
    public $_fval, $_sval;
    public function __construct( $fval, $sval ) {
        $this->_fval = $fval;
        $this->_sval = $sval;
    }
    public function add() {
        return $this->_fval + $this->_sval;
    }
    public function subtract() {
        return $this->_fval - $this->_sval;
    }
    public function multiply() {
        return $this->_fval * $this->_sval;
    }
    public function divide() {
        return $this->_fval / $this->_sval;
    }
}
?>

<html>
<body>

<form action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?> method='post'>
<p>
    <label for="num-a">a</label>: <input type="number" id="num-a" name="num-a">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="num-b">b</label>: <input type="number" id="num-b" name="num-b">
</p>

   <label for="operation-add">Add</label>
   <input type='radio' name="operation" value='add' id="operation-add">
   
   <label for='operation-multiply'>Multiply</label>
   <input type='radio' name="operation" value='multiply' id='operation-multiply'>
   
   <label for='operation-subtract'>Subtract</label>
   <input type='radio' name="operation" value='subtract' id='operation-subtract'>

   <label for='operation-divide'>Divide</label>
   <input type='radio' name="operation" value='divide' id='operation-divide'>
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
 // You need to verify the values have been submitted before using them
if ( isset($_POST['num-a']) && isset($_POST['num-b']) &&  isset($_POST['operation']) ):
 $x = $_POST['num-a']; 
 $y = $_POST['num-b']; 
 $operation = $_POST['operation'];

//instantiate your calculator
 $calc = new MyCalculator($x, $y);

// then print out the results of the calculation
 echo "<p>Your result is: <strong>";
 switch ($operation) {
   case "add":
     echo $calc->add();
     break;
   case "subtract":
     echo $calc->subtract();
     break;
   case "divide":
     echo $calc->divide();
     break;
   case "add":
     echo $calc->multiply();
     break;
   default:
     echo "Unsupported operation used";
     break;
 }
 echo "</strong></p>";
}
?>


  [1]: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code. My code was missing a lot of things. With the help of your code it worked.